# "Unable to find libsodium" issue with PyTezos

Tags: pytezos

I have some PyTezos code working on Linux. However, when I try to run it on MacOS 13 on an M2 processor, I get an `Unable to find libsodium` error.

I do have libSodium installed on my system:

```
brew info libsodium 
==> libsodium: stable 1.0.18 (bottled), HEAD
NaCl networking and cryptography library
https://libsodium.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.18_1 (73 files, 777.9KB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-03-28 at 20:09:46
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libsodium.rb
License: ISC
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 18,472 (30 days), 96,278 (90 days), 129,356 (365 days)
install-on-request: 445 (30 days), 1,993 (90 days), 2,765 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I even tried exporting its path as described on other forums:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.18_1:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Here is the full stack trace:

```
python -m unittest persimmon_daemons.tests.consumer_tests

/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py:34: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/tests/consumer_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import consumer
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/consumer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pytezos import pytezos
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pytezos.client import PyTezosClient
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pytezos.block.header import BlockHeader
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/block/header.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pytezos.block.forge import bump_fitness
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/block/forge.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pytezos.michelson.forge import forge_array
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/michelson/forge.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pytezos.crypto.key import blake2b_32
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytezos/crypto/key.py", line 59, in <module>
    import pysodium  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/tezette/dev/Persimmon/persimmon_daemons/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysodium/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Unable to find libsodium')
ValueError: Unable to find libsodium
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get PyTezos working?

Comment: This is probably the right path (exporting LD PATH), just can be different env variable, check out this thread: https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/issues/282

Try also setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on tbinetruy's comment on https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/issues/282, setting the following environment variable fixed the issue:

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/`

Answer (score 1):

I use an M1 and have also had problems with various tezos tools.

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but an alternate solution for Tezos development on mac is to use a devcontainer. I have swapped to this for all my tezos projects and that let's me avoid the compatibility and install issues.

Here's a devcontainer I just made for pyTezos. There are some basic instructions in the readme

https://github.com/grum-tez/pyTezosDC

If you fork and then clone that onto a local volume using VSCode and you'll have a working environment more or less immediately